# HashMap find() with arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have a class named `Machine` defined as :

```
class Machine
{
  private String name;

  Machine() { name = null; }

  // set , get methods of String name

}
```

I also have a class named `MachineAtt` implementing an interface `Att` like:

```
// Att interface 
 interface Att
  {
   void add(Machine obj);
   Machine find(String name)
  }

// MachineAtt class
class MachineAtt implements Att
 {
   protected Map<String,Machine> hashTable = new HashMap<String,Machine>();

  // ovveride methods from interface Att
  }
```

the main function is:

```
Machine car = new Machine();
car.setName("MB");
//create an object of MachineAtt
MachineAtt foundit = new MachineAtt();

foundit.add(car);
foundit.find("MB");
```

My question is: how can I do the same but with an **array**? 
for example, I want to `foundit.add(someArray)` and then I search certain item in this **array** by using method `find();` I hope you get what I mean. Any ideas?

Comment: Are the attribute `name` in class `Machine` same as the key to the map on which you are storing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your  `addAll(Machine[] machines)` method is like this.

```
void addAll(Machine[] machines){
     for(Machine m:machines){
         add(m); 
     }
}
```

Your `findAll(String[] names)` method is like this.

```
Machine[] findAll(String[] names){
     ArrayList<Machine> machines =new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
      for(String s:names){
         Machine m  = find(s); 
         if(m!=null){
             machines.add(m);
         }
     }
     return machines.toArray(new Machine[0])
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea and it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method like

```
void addAll(Machine[] machines)
```

and in its implementation, you add all elements from this array into the hashtable.

Answer (score 0):

add methods

```
void add(Machine[] arr);
Machine[] find(String[] names);
```

and implement them in your class

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked to this with an array i have tried it with the arrays. But I would rather suggest to go with an `ArrayList` as it is dynamic and insertion and searching is also fast and easy. Never mind try the following snippet.

```
class Machine
{
  private String name;
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
  public String getName() {
    return name;
}
  Machine() { name = null; }
}

interface Att
{
 void add(Machine obj);
 Machine find(String name);
}

//MachineAtt class
class MachineAtt implements Att
{
 protected Machine[] arr = new Machine[10];


@Override
    public void add(Machine obj) {
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++ )
        {
            if(arr[i]==null)
                arr[i] = obj;
        }

    }
@Override
    public Machine find(String name) {
    Machine mac = null; 
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            if(arr[i].getName().equals(name))
                mac = arr[i];
        }
        return mac;
    }
}


public class TEst {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Machine car = new Machine();
        car.setName("MB");
        //create an object of MachineAtt
        MachineAtt foundit = new MachineAtt();

        foundit.add(car);
        foundit.find("MB");
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice, but if i have for example a lot of items(1000 and so on) and i need to find only one item. Is hashmap more suitable than an equals method? i assume that you do not need to compare all elements, you need just check the hashcode of your certain item. isn't it? :)